# SonarQube 5.6.6: Error OWASP ZAP & Dependency Check Plugin

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, owasp, zap

While setting up the dashboard widgets on SonarQube 5.6.6 to display results from OWASP Dependency Check & ZAP and Xanitizer I encounter the following error message:

> An error occurred while trying to display the widget "xanitizer". Please contact the administrator.

I have SonarQube running on a Windows 2008 Server R2 as a test instance.

What I did so far:

1. Installed the relevant plugins
2. Configured the plugin POM file with Windows paths (like: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ZAP-Scanning\reports`)
3. Created a reports either by a Jenkins job (for OWASP stuff) or by Xanitizer app.
4. Pointed SonarQube to the absolute path of Xanitizer report file in SonarQube GIU
5. Created each a SonarQube project manually
6. Linked the projects to the corresponding widget
7. The result is always the error message you can find above.

As a workaround I contacted Steve Springet directly. He pointed me to some GitHub pages, which did not help.

As I am not a developer: Is there any tutorial that might help?

Implementing Checkmarx plugin took some minutes to have scan results displayed.
Apparently I got stuck somewhere in the sonar.property files or the bridge between Windows and Linux syntax...

If helpful I can share the property and POM files with you.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Xanitizer plugin. It has been fixed with version 1.4.0 of the plugin.